# Adding a semaphore retry login in my code

Tags: c, multithreading, semaphore

### Current scenario

I am having a binary semaphore and I am doing some operations on a variable before doing that I am acquiring semaphore lock(its non blocking semaphore) and if some other process or say thread wants to acquire it, it will fail saying semaphore timed out.

### Want to implement

A retry mechanism wherein if semaphore lock fails because of time out it will call my retry mechanism where I am planning to retry if lock has failed with 1 second delay and 5 retries.

My question is what does semaphore lock returns and below is my approach

```
errorhandl semretry(){
    int count =5;
    errorhandl err = NULL;
    do{
        err = semaphore.lock(); // <<< to me it looks that err will always be NULL
        if(semaphore.timeout()) {
            sleep (1);
            count --;
        }
    }while(count > 0);
}
```

Any suggestion on this approach. I want to do more on this on the basis of lock is acquired or not. Please suggest what else can be done.

Comment: Please format your code, it is unreadable.

Comment: What semaphore library do you use ?

Comment: Internally we use posix semaphore libraries above it we have wrapper functions ...

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use any of the following 2 implementations. I would advise the 2nd one.

```
int semretry(sem_t *sem)
{
    int count =5;
    int err;
    do{
        err = sem_trywait(sem);
        if(errno == EAGAIN) {
            err = EAGAIN;
            sleep(1);
            count --;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }while(count > 0);
    return err;
}

int semretry(sem_t *sem)
{
    int count =5;
    int err;
    struct timespec timeout;
    do{
        clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, &timeout);
        timeout.tv_sec += 1;
        err = sem_timedwait(sem, &timeout);
        if(err != 0) {
            err = EAGAIN;
            count --;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }while(count > 0);
    return err;
}
```